# What does an '@' in a php file string mean?

Tags: php, file-upload, syntax

I am having trouble googling this, so please bear with me.

I have a code example that is about uploading files and there is the assignment of a temporary file to an array like this:

```
 $postparam['file1'] = '@../res/example.pdf';
```

I would like to know what the effect of the @ character is. I know about error suppression with @ but i am confused about the use *inside* the string.

Thanks.

Comment: how is it used later?

Comment: ^- this. In PHP a string is a string, it can contain any characters. Most likely the @ is replaced later by a method in your code

Comment: It is submitted to an API via multipart upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: The example uses cURL and that is why the @ is required as a prefix to the filename.

> @filename
>   This will make curl load data from the given file (including any newlines), URL-encode that data and pass it on in the POST.

[Source](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)